# Can a druid use Wild Companion and Wild Shape simultaneously?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, druid, wild-shape, optional-rules

The context for this is that a PC druid that is not yet level 8, wants to achieve flight by using the Wild Companion feature from *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* to summon a familiar with a fly speed like an owl, and then turn themselves into a small creature like a crab with their Wild Shape that the owl will then carry, thus achieving flight.

So the question is can they have Wild Companion and Wild Shape active simultaneously?

Comment: Is there any reason you think these might *not* be able to be used simultaneously?

Comment: @Exempt-Medic they both use the charges for wild shape so I thought there might be something that restricts that, like you can only use one charge of wildshape at a time, but point taken it seems like no such rule exists.

Comment: Related: "[Can the Circle of the Stars druid use their Starry Form feature in conjunction with their Wild Shape form?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165415)"

Comment: Be something that the owl would eat, looks more natural. A crab would draw suspicious looks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes, you can

The Wild Companion feature you gain at 2nd level says:

> You gain the ability to summon a spirit that assumes an animal form: as an action, **you can expend a use of your Wild Shape feature** to cast the *find familiar* spell, without material components

The Wild Shape feature (also gained at second level) says:

> Starting at 2nd level, you can use your action to magically assume the shape of a beast that you have seen before. **You can use this feature twice.** You regain expended uses when you finish a short or long rest.

So you have two uses of Wild Shape per short rest. You could spend one of them to summon a familiar and the other one to transform with Wild Shape. There is nothing that states that you cannot use both uses at the same time; only, normally if you use the Wild Shape to transform a second time, you of course lose your original transformation.

The kinds of beasts you can transform into is only limited by CR, and that they originally may not have a fly speed. A crab would qualify.